# Multiple view for Single Router in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have a common `HTML` where the header got to change after login.

```
<div class="masthead clearfix">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3 class="masthead-brand"></h3>
              <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
                <li class="active"  ng-show="NotLoggedIn" ><a href="#/login">Login &nbsp;<b>|</b></a></li>
                <li  ng-show="NotLoggedIn"><a href="#/register">Register</a></li>
              <li class="active"  ng-show="LoggedIn" ><a href="#/login">Welcome &nbsp;{{UserName}}<b>|</b></a></li>
                <li  ng-show="LoggedIn" ><a href="#/register">LogOut</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div ng-view class="mailContent">

          </div>
```

app.js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl : 'template/home.html',
        controller : 'HomeController'
    })
    .when('/login',{
        templateUrl :'template/login.html',
        controller : 'LoginController'

    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo :'/'});
});
```

once the login in success `NotLoggedIn` should hide and `LoggedIn` should show. How to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou can use `ng-if` in AngularJS. You have to assign a boolean value for `ng-if`. So that the DOM which is  having the value `false` will get removed and the one which is having `true` will be  displayed

```
<ul class="nav masthead-nav">
  <li class="active"  ng-if="NotLoggedIn" >
        <a href="#/login">Login &nbsp;<b>|</b></a>
  </li>
  <li  ng-if="NotLoggedIn">
        <a href="#/register">Register</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"  ng-if="LoggedIn" >
        <a href="#/login">Welcome &nbsp;{{UserName}}<b>|</b></a>
  </li>
  <li  ng-if="LoggedIn" >
       <a href="#/register">LogOut</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **service** that maintains the login state of the user so that this information can be **shared** amongst controllers.

Inject the service into the **login controller** to perform the actual login.

Inject the service into **main controller** to have access to the state and adjust the user interface accordantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the two headers in the top of pages and use "ng-if" directive to enable/disable the desire template. For example:

```
'LoginController'

$scope.currentSection = "login";


'index.html'

<div ng-if="currentSection === login" ng-include="'views/headerLogOut.html'"></div>
<div ng-if="currentSection !== login" ng-include="'views/headerLogoIn.html'"></div>
```